# После миграции на Spring Boot 3.0.0 с 2.7.0 не обнаруживаются бины

Tags: java, spring

Вот такую ситуацию вижу с каждым бином, поставлю для теста `required=false`, дальше выскакивают остальные аннотации, по типу, `entity`, `component`, `repository` и т.д.

Подскажите, может кто-то сталкивался с подобным.

Сообщение об ошибке:

> 2023-10-30T10:46:49.792+02:00  **WARN** 1340 --- [           main]
> **ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext** : Exception encountered
> during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name '**accountMapper**': Unsatisfied dependency
> expressed through field '**coreModuleAccountMapper**': No qualifying bean
> of type
> 'project.module.core.data.mapper.module.user.account.**CoreModuleAccountMapper**'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate. Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field imageRepository in project.module.file_storage.service.impl.ImageServiceImpl required a bean of type 'project.module.file_storage.repository.files.ImageRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'project.module.file_storage.repository.files.ImageRepository' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно, вы предлагаете гадать по паре строчек из лога?

Comment: Это не пара строчек, а сама ерора, как я написал данная ошибка вылазит со всеми бинами, возможно кто сталкивался, что в этом такого?
Судя по минусам на stackoverflow крайне токсичное комьюнити, видимо не стоит здесь искать помощи

Comment: Вопрос относится к миграции **Spring** или **Spring Boot**?  Вы мигрируете со **Spring Boot 2.7** на **Spring Boot 3.0**?  Вы пользовались руководством по миграции [Spring Boot 3.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide)?

Comment: @NowhereMan да, пользовался, проблему нашел, на гиде по миграции сказано, что для автоконфигураций теперь нужен META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports, но spring.factories все равно должны поддерживаться, на деле, нет, такая клоунада

Comment: Хм, в гиде для миграции вроде как сказано, что `spring.factories` поддерживались в Spring Boot 2.7 для обратной совместимости, а в 3.0 уже нет: _[With this release] support for registering auto-configurations in `spring.factories` using the `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration` key has been removed in favor of the imports file_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для автоконфигураций теперь нужен META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports, но spring.factories все равно должны поддерживаться, на деле, нет

META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports
в него заносятся пути ваших конфигурационных класов

Comment: В целом вопрос и ответ полезны.  Вероятно стоит уточнить, какие именно изменения вы сделали на своей стороне, чтобы решить эту проблему.